# How to insert data from one list<structure> to another list<structure>

Tags: c++

I have two list one with 2 different structures and need to map it properly.

For example i have two list test and test2

```
list<structure> test;
list<structure1> test2
```

Now i need to insert the data from first list to the second one which is failing as it has two different structures but there are few variable which matches. Can someone help me how to map and insert data from first to second.

Comment: By `list<structure>`, do you mean you have a `list` of `structure`, or a `list` implemented with certain `structure`?

Comment: @user3064181 Do you need additional information or did the answer help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// ...

std::list<structure> test;
std::list<structure1> test2;

std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), std::back_inserter(test2),
    [](const structure& in) -> structure1 {
        return {list, the, fields, in, structure1};
    });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4hEG1PK74)